# Why is OnTriggerEnter not called when my objects do not have Rigidbodies?

Tags: unity, c#, collider

I am trying to get my enemy to take damage, however it is not working. I know the reason: the box colliders on not triggering the `OnTriggerEnter` message. I do not know why. Here is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyBaseScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float health;   
    private Weapon weaponGettingHitBy;

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
    {
        Debug.Log("OnTriggerEnter was called");
        if (col.gameObject.CompareTag("Weapon"))
        {
            weaponGettingHitBy = new Weapon(
               col.gameObject, 
               col.gameObject.GetComponent<WeaponBaseScript>().damageDealing
            );            
            health -= weaponGettingHitBy.damageDealt;

            Debug.Log("Took damage from weapon.");
        }   
    }
}
```

The code for weapons

```
using UnityEngine;

public class WeaponBaseScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float damageDealing;
}
```

Images of the box colliders:

(I know that some of the box colliders are off it is because I was testing around, assume all are enabled)

[image: The sword]

[image: goblin]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you can see from the [Collision action matrix in the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html):

**Trigger messages are sent upon collision**

|  | Static Collider | Rigidbody Collider | Kinematic Rigidbody Collider | Static Trigger Collider | Rigidbody Trigger Collider | Kinematic Rigidbody Trigger Collider |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Static Collider** |  |  |  |  | Y | Y |
| **Rigidbody Collider** |  |  |  | Y | Y | Y |
| **Kinematic Rigidbody Collider** |  |  |  | Y | Y | Y |
| **Static Trigger Collider** |  | Y | Y |  | Y | Y |
| **Rigidbody Trigger Collider** | Y | Y | Y | Y | Y | Y |
| **Kinematic Rigidbody Trigger Collider** | Y | Y | Y | Y | Y | Y |

In order to generate an `OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)` message, at least one of the colliders involved has to have the `isTrigger` flag set, and at least one of the objects involved has to have a `Rigidbody` attached (either at the same level or in one of its parents).

Colliders with no `Rigidbody` are considered "static" - the engine expects they will not move, and so it does not check for collisions between them. You should always use a `Rigidbody` on physics colliders that you will be moving. If you don't want the physics engine to integrate their velocity automatically, use the kinematic mode so you can keep full control of their movement while still getting collision checking.